# How to store the app usage statistics in a text file?

Tags: java, android, data-storage

I am developing an app which would give usage statistics that are installed on my phone, but I want to store these statistics (i.e how long the app was open and at what time etc.) in a file rather than just displaying it on the screen.

I expect the app to run in the background and save the app usage on a text file

Comment: Hi, search the web to see how you write to file in android and create some StatisticsUtilsWriter class in your project which will have function for your statistics. My advice don't write to file each time you have something, store it in cache and write only when you have enough data or the app about to die (this applies only if your app generates  statistics in high frequency.

Comment: @MaksimNovikov I am a newbie on Android studio. Could you please elaborate or give me an example of how should I go about this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to store this data either in Shared preferences or in a database like [ObjectBox](https://objectbox.io/).

Comment: I wanted it to be in a text file.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also providing same as you thing but for me it's Parental Control app. So i'm showing   the method used for storing history of app.

```
    private void history(AccessibilityEvent event) {
    SharedPreferences sf = getSharedPreferences("TempApp", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sf.edit();

        Log.i("eventSource", event.getPackageName().toString());
        try {
            appName = getPackageManager().getApplicationLabel(getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(event.getPackageName().toString(), PackageManager.GET_META_DATA)).toString();
            Log.i("CurrentApplication", appName);
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String tempApp = sf.getString("appName", "");
        if (tempApp.equals(appName)) {
            Log.i("Current", "inside if ");
        } else {
            editor.putString("appName", appName).apply();
            Calendar cl = Calendar.getInstance();
            String time, hour, minute, second;
             hour = (cl.get(Calendar.HOUR) < 10) ? "0" + cl.get(Calendar.HOUR) : ""+ cl.get(Calendar.HOUR);
             minute = (cl.get(Calendar.MINUTE) < 10) ? "0" + cl.get(Calendar.MINUTE) : ""+ cl.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
             second = (cl.get(Calendar.SECOND) < 10) ? "0" + cl.get(Calendar.SECOND) : ""+ cl.get(Calendar.SECOND);
             time = hour + ":" + minute + ":" + second;
            if (cl.get(Calendar.AM_PM) == 0)
                time += " AM";
            else
                time += " PM";
            int timeStart= cl.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)*60*60+cl.get(Calendar.MINUTE)*60+cl.get(Calendar.SECOND);
            editor.putInt("nowTime",timeStart).apply();
            HistoryDB hDB = new HistoryDB(getApplicationContext());
            hDB.insertData(appName);
            hDB.update(tempApp, "EndTime", time);
            int timeUsed=sf.getInt("nowTime",0)-sf.getInt("prevTime",0);
            hDB.update(tempApp, "TimeUsed",String.valueOf(timeUsed));
            hDB.update(appName, "StartTime", time);
            editor.putInt("prevTime",timeStart).apply();
        }
    }
```

History.java

```
public class HistoryDB  extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private static String DB_NAME = "History.db";
private static int DB_VR = 1;
private static String DB_TABLE = "HistoryData";
private static SQLiteDatabase dbb;
public HistoryDB(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VR);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("create table  " +DB_TABLE + "(AppName text,StartTime text ,EndTime text,TimeUsed Integer);");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}
void insertData(String appName)
{
    dbb = getWritableDatabase();
    dbb.execSQL("insert into "+ DB_TABLE + "(AppName,StartTime,EndTime,TimeUsed) values('"+appName+"',' ','                  ',0);");
    dbb.close();
}

 void update(String appName, String colName, String time) {
    dbb = getWritableDatabase();
    dbb.execSQL("update "+DB_TABLE+" set "+colName+"='"+time+"' where AppName='"+appName+"'");
    dbb.close();
}

 ArrayList<String> getData(String colName)
{
    dbb=getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cr=dbb.rawQuery("select "+colName+" from "+DB_TABLE,null);
    ArrayList<String> arrayList=new ArrayList<>();
    while(cr.moveToNext()){
        arrayList.add(cr.getString(0));
    }
    dbb.close();
    cr.close();
    return arrayList;
}
```

}

Comment: HistoryDB is using shared preferences?

Comment: @MaksimNovikov Can't understand what u r asking.

Comment: What is inside HistoryDB class?

Comment: Ok good now he can see how to implement it. Happy you not using SharedPreferences for this :)

Comment: @MnkDude I want to store it in the text file. I am a newbie to the android studio, so it is a little tricky for me. Thanks for your answer

Comment: @xeniazee why u want to store in text file rather than using DB or light weight Name/value pair (NVP) SharedPreferences ?

Comment: @MnkDude I want to later integrate this with another app that is the reason, even if I  want to use the shared preferences, I would have zero knowledge on how to create for this particular app.